# Why is "symbol" part of the names of some CUDA functions?

Tags: cuda, gpu

Several CUDA function names have the word Symbol in them.

```
e.g. cudaMemcpyToSymbol() , cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(), cudaGetSymbolAddress() etc.
```

The explanation of what these functions do is clear enough in the Programming guide. What I 
dont get is the choice of the word "symbol" in naming these functions. What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use the word "symbol" because it is possible for these functions to take the name of a device variable **as a string**. For instance:

```
cudaMemcpyToSymbol("my_var_d", my_var_h, sizeof(my_var_d));
```

Presumably, this strange syntax allows some use case that I have yet to think of :)

Comment: There is an elf format symbol table lurking in each post CUDA 3.0 cubin payload and contexts/modules has always supported retrieval of kernels, textures, variables by name. See functions like `cuModuleGetGlobal` for an example.

Answer (score 0):

This "symbol" is a device variable.